# Rich text or HTML code into google maps description

Tags: google-maps

As you can see from this video or this following picture

[image]
with the previous version of google-maps you can add rich text or HTML code when editing the description.
[Add rich content](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujwrD4PJAKE)

How can I add rich content (HTML code) with new google version of google-maps?
Here is a picture from the new versione of google-maps where I would like to add HTML code.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: @putvande I would like to add a link to the description. I updated the question with a new picture to be more clear.

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same requirements